# Insert line break into SQL query return after concatenating columns whilst skipping NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I want to concatenate several columns together and separate each column return with a line break taking into account `NULL` values.

For example, I have the following data table (`[dbo].[Address]`):

```
Name         Address_line1    Address_line2   Address_line 3   Postcode
Mr Smith     1 Smith Street   NULL            Ireland          AB1 1CD
Mr Jones     1 Jones Road     Wales           NULL             EF2 3GH
Mrs White    1 White Way      England         UK               NULL
```

I want to return the following:

```
Name         Address
Mr Smith     1 Smith Street,
             Ireland,
             AB1 1CD
Mr Jones     1 Jones Road,
             Wales,
             EF2 3GH
Mrs White    1 White Way,
             England,
             UK
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You can take care of this in presentation layer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `+` operator and `COALESCE()` :

```
WITH T AS (SELECT 'Mr Smith' AS NAME, '1 Smith Street' AS Address_Line1, NULL AS Address_line2, 'Ireland' AS Address_Line3, 'AB1 1CD' AS PostCode
UNION SELECT 'Mr Jones' AS NAME, '1 Jones Road' AS Address_Line1, 'Wales' AS Address_line2, NULL AS Address_Line3, 'EF2 3GH' AS PostCode
UNION SELECT 'Mrs White' AS NAME, '1 White Way' AS Address_Line1, 'England' AS Address_line2, 'UK' AS Address_Line3, NULL AS PostCode
)
  SELECT NAME, ADDRESS_LINE1  
+ COALESCE(','+ CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)  + Address_line2 , '') 
+ COALESCE ',' + (CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)  +Address_line3 ,'')
+ COALESCE(',' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +POSTCODE,'') AS ADDRESS
FROM T
```

Output:

```
NAME      
--------- --------------------------------------------
Mr Jones  1 Jones Road,
   Wales,
   EF2 3GH
Mr Smith  1 Smith Street,
   Ireland,
   AB1 1CD
Mrs White 1 White Way,
   England,
   UK
```

Comment: Wouldn't the concatenation with the chars make null values not null?

Comment: No, but I have to edit my query, because I didn't see POSTCODE can be NULL and I have to eliminate pending ','

Comment: Done it. @Stefano: in genere è il contrario: se tenti di concatenare stringa con NULL, ottieni NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
select name,
       replace(stuff( coalesce('[sep]' + address_line1, '') +
                      coalesce('[sep]' + address_line2, '') +
                      coalesce('[sep]' + address_line3, ''),
                      1, 5, ''
                    ), '[sep]', '
'
               )
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHAR(13)` like

```
select Name, 
Address_line1 + ',' +char(13) + Address_line2 + ',' + char(13) + Address_line 3 as address 
from [dbo].[Address]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
name, 
CONCAT(
COALESCE(Address_line1,''), ', ', 
COALESCE(Address_line2,''), ', ', 
COALESCE(Address_line3,''), ', ', 
COALESCE(Postcode,'')
) AS address 
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Please comment the code you provided, helping to understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using ISNULL() with Char (13) + CHAR(10):

```
SELECT 
Name 
, ISNULL(Address_line1 + ',' + CHAR(13)) + CHAR(10), '') + ISNULL(Address_line2 + ',' + CHAR(13)) + CHAR(10), '') + ISNULL(Address_line 3, '') as address 
from [dbo].[Address]
```